# Reply this css code on styled componentes

Tags: css, styled-components

Hi guys i have one css code working on pure css, but i need to pass then for styled-components or material ui, and work too, anyone can help me ?

```
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 9999px 0 0 9999px;
  margin: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#top,
#bottom {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#top {
  top: -30px;
}

#bottom {
  bottom: -30px;
}

#top::before,
#bottom::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 200%;
  width: 200%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 100px blue;
  z-index: -1;
}

#top::before {
  top: -100%;
}
```

This code is used for create a curve on css, but i need to do the same in the styled component.

I try do to the same using makeStyles of material ui but i can't too.

Comment: what is a problem with?

Comment: i need to reply in styled-components, not pure css

Comment: understood, what exactly you have a problem with?